# How can I get 'start' Query String Parameter in Datatable server side processing?

Tags: php, zend-framework, datatables

I am using server side processing approach to create Datatables and I need to get 'start' parameter that is sent to server when making request. I have tried `$_GET['start']` and `$_REQUEST['start']`, but none of them works. Could you please help me?
By the way I am working with Zend Framework.

Comment: Either of those should work. Are you hitting script.php?start=foo

Comment: Show us the code snippet how you get the parameter so we can help.

Comment: Okay, now I figured out the problem. $_GET['start'] was returning integer values in quotes so tried (integer) $_GET['start'] and it worked.